# A compact metric space is totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

There are lots of questions on this issue in the site. The original statement reads

> A metric space is compact if and only if it is both complete and totally bounded.

I am only interested in proving `If a metric space is compact, then it is totally bounded`, following my definition of totally bounded:

> A metric space X is totally bounded if for each $r>0$ there exists a finite set $F \subseteq X$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(x,F)<r$ for each $x\in X$; i.e. $X = \cup \lbrace B_r(y): y\in F \rbrace$. (For $x\in X$, $\operatorname{dist}(x,A) = \operatorname{inf}\lbrace \rho(x,a): a\in A \rbrace$)

Now, if $X$ is compact, then every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover, say $\mathcal{U}$. Then we can select $y\in U_y$, for $U_y\in\mathcal{U}$, such that $B_{r_y}(y) \subseteq U_y$. However, $X\neq \cup B_{r_y}(y)$, if for instance $B_{r_y}(y) \subset U_y$ (more concretely I am thinking here in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $U_y=(0,1)\cup (5,5.1)$, then the neighborhood of $y$ does not include some real numbers)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a cover, yet. You're assuming that $X$ is compact, so you *know* that every open cover has a finite sub cover. So, what you want to do is take an appropriate open cover, then reduce it to a finite subcover using the compactness, and somehow, this should give you the finite set that you're looking for. This is how you use an assumption like compactness.

Hint: Since you want to show that $X$ is totally bounded, you need to start by fixing $r$. Then, cover your space with balls of radius $r$ centered at every point. Use compactness to extract a finite subcover.